# my code skips a part

Tags: c#, sqlite

My code skips the part where it reads the table from another database.
It has to use the for each for my code to work. When i use a different database kind it works but with sqlite it can't read the insides of the database.
The whole code is to migrate databases to different programs.

```
DataTable schemaUserTables = m_objDbSource.GetSchemaUserTables();
DataRow[] sortedUserTables = schemaUserTables.Select("TABLE_NAME <> 'sysdiagrams'",
                "TABLE_SCHEMA ASC, TABLE_NAME ASC", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
foreach (DataRow schemaUserTable in sortedUserTables)
{
    object oSchema = schemaUserTable["TABLE_SCHEMA"];
    if (Convert.IsDBNull(oSchema))
    {
        m_clbTables.Items.Add(schemaUserTable["TABLE_NAME"]);
    }
    else
    {
        m_clbTables.Items.Add(schemaUserTable["TABLE_SCHEMA"] + "." + schemaUserTable["TABLE_NAME"]);
    }
}
```

This is where the code gets the schema.

```
public DataTable GetSchemaUserTables()
    {
        //if (DbType == dbTypeEnum.Sqlite)
        //{
        //    return SchemaSqliteDb();
        //}
        // We only want user tables, not system tables
        string[] restrictions = new string[4];
        restrictions[3] = (DbType == dbTypeEnum.AccessAcc || DbType == dbTypeEnum.AccessXP) 
            ? "TABLE" : "BASE TABLE";
        NewConnection();
        OpenConnectionIfNeeded();
        DataTable rVal = m_connection.GetSchema("Tables", restrictions);
        CloseConnection();
        return rVal;
    }
```

Comment: did you get any datarow in sortedUserTables?

Comment: {System.Data.DataRow[0]}
it says this is inside there when I am debuging

Comment: Can you add a watch to schemaUserTable & sortedUserTables values & check the difference for other dbs & sqlLite

Comment: the difference is in the loop.

Comment: the difference is in datarow. with other dbs it says DataRow[65]

Comment: did you get records in schemaUsertables?

Comment: yes. the tables are in there.